# Numeric citation biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have the usual problem of non-numeric way of citation of Biblatex. Prior to compilation I deleted auxiliary files. When I copied code into Overleaf it compiled correctly. As my IDE I'm using TexStudio. What else could go wrong?

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex} %the same problem with that line
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sortcites,sorting=nty,backref,natbib,hyperref]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
First citation:

\cite{avron2003topological}

Second citation: 

\cite{ozawa2019topological}

Third citation:

\cite{latexcompanion}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Additionally I get error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
```

Comment: First of all: Welcome! After deleting the *auxiliary files* have you compiled the bibliography? in TexStudio `Tools > Bibliography` or `F8`?

Comment: I did -- nothing changes.

Comment: You need to run Biber not BibTeX

Comment: As Joseph says: You need to run Biber on this document, but the  `.log` suggests you run BibTeX. If you let TeXstudio compile your document for you, you need to configure it to use Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: It says:            ```INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.5.
This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.14) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1```

Comment: That message says your `biblatex` and Biber versions are out of sync. Update your TeX installation (via `tlmgr` if you have TeX live or via the MikTeX Console if you have MikTeX, recall that on muti-user MikTeX installs, you have to run the updated once in Admin and once in User mode). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864.

Comment: Did you manage to update your TeX installation? If not, can you explain if you are using MikTeX or TeX live and how you installed your system? Please also explain in more details how you tried to update and how it failed for you.